# SQL Calculate a Total Time in a specific State

Tags: sql-server, date

I have these datas in a Table

```
_____DateTime____|Variable__|Value
2017/03/29 23:00:00 | Variable1   | 1     
2017/03/31 01:00:00 | Variable1   | 0     
2017/03/31 02:00:00 | Variable1   | 1     
2017/03/31 03:00:00 | Variable1   | 0     
2017/03/31 04:00:00 | Variable2   | 1     
2017/03/31 23:00:00 | Variable1   | 1     
2017/04/01 01:00:00 | Variable1   | 0
```

And I would like to calculate the total duration where each variable was in state 1 between two date

For example between for Var1 2017/03/31 00:00:00 and 2017/04/01 00:00:00
The result is :

```
1 hour between 2017/03/31 00:00:00 and 2017/03/31 01:00:00
1 hour between 2017/03/31 02:00:00 and 2017/03/31 03:00:00
1 hour between 2017/03/31 23:00:00 and 2017/04/01 00:00:00
```

So the result I want for Var1 should be 3 hours

For example between for Var2 2017/03/31 00:00:00 and 2017/04/01 00:00:00
The result is :
1 hour between 2017/03/31 04:00:00 and 2017/04/01 00:00:00 (no value before but because it change to 1 I suppose that it was 0 before)

So the result I want for Var2 should be 20 hours

**Variable**|__Time in Value (second)

Variable1   | 180

Variable2   | 1200

If someone can help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this always by hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server 2012+ (because of `lead()` and `concat()`)

Using a stacked cte to generate an hours table to `inner join` a subquery that uses the [**`lead()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) window function to get the next date for status change partitioned by `Variable`.

To adapt for prior versions, use an `outer apply()` to get the next `dt` for each variable instead of `lead()`; and regular string concatenation with proper conversions instead of `concat()`.

```
declare @fromdate datetime = '20170331 00:00:00';
declare @thrudate datetime = '20170401 00:00:00';
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, hours as (
  select top ((datediff(hour, @fromdate, @thrudate)+1))
      [DateHour]=dateadd(hour,(row_number() over (order by (select 1)) -1),@fromdate)
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo 
                cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
   order by 1
)
select variable, value
  , hours = count(h.datehour)
  , start_dt = convert(varchar(20),min(h.datehour),120)
  , end_dt   = convert(varchar(20),end_dt,120)
  , txt = concat(
            count(h.datehour),' '
          , case when count(h.datehour) < 2 then 'hour' else 'hours' end
          , ' between '
          , convert(varchar(20),min(h.datehour),120)
          , ' and '
          , convert(varchar(20),end_dt,120)
    )
from hours h
  inner join (
  select 
      variable
    , value
    , start_dt = dt
    , end_dt   = case when coalesce(lead(dt) over (partition by variable order by dt),@thrudate) > @thrudate 
                        then @thrudate 
                      else coalesce(lead(dt) over (partition by variable order by dt),@thrudate) 
                      end
  from t
    ) s
    on h.datehour >= s.start_dt
   and h.datehour <  s.end_dt
  where h.datehour >= @fromdate
    and h.datehour <  @thrudate
    and s.value = 1
group by variable, value, start_dt, end_dt
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ZBWP22523

returns:

```
+-----------+-------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| variable  | value | hours |      start_dt       |       end_dt        |                             txt                              |
+-----------+-------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable1 |     1 |     1 | 2017-03-31 00:00:00 | 2017-03-31 01:00:00 | 1 hour between 2017-03-31 00:00:00 and 2017-03-31 01:00:00   |
| Variable1 |     1 |     1 | 2017-03-31 02:00:00 | 2017-03-31 03:00:00 | 1 hour between 2017-03-31 02:00:00 and 2017-03-31 03:00:00   |
| Variable1 |     1 |     1 | 2017-03-31 23:00:00 | 2017-04-01 01:00:00 | 1 hour between 2017-03-31 23:00:00 and 2017-04-01 01:00:00   |
| Variable2 |     1 |    20 | 2017-03-31 04:00:00 | 2017-04-01 00:00:00 | 20 hours between 2017-03-31 04:00:00 and 2017-04-01 00:00:00 |
+-----------+-------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If you need to do this often, you might consider creating an actual table for hours. Otherwise, using the stacked cte is as fast as most other options, and is much faster than a recursive cte as the number of values generated increases.

Number and Calendar table reference:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 2 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 3 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)
- [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in SQL Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in SQL Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)
- [TSQL Function to Determine Holidays in SQL Server - Tim Cullen](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1537/tsql-function-to-determine-holidays-in-sql-server/)
- [F_TABLE_DATE - Michael Valentine Jones](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=61519)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it works very well. In fact, I wanted only the duration in a specific state for each Variable (and in hour was not a good idea)!!!

Comment: Correction @SqlZim. It doesn't work because it gives me the hour between 2017-03-29 23:00:00 and 2017-03-31 01:00:00. And because my query is starting at 2017-03-31 00:00:00 I only want the hour between  2017-03-31 00:00:00 and 2017-03-31 01:00:00

Comment: @StéphanF Updated to use `min(h.datehour)`